# jQuery find previous li with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner">
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="1"><a></a>Header1</li>//this is needed
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>//I am here
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="2"><a></a>Header2</li>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get `li` with class `dropdown-header` which is upper to the clicked `li a`. If `li` with class `dropdown-header` clicked, it should be ignored. Here `li` with `data-optgroup` 1 should be selected. I tried the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    var html = $($this[0].parentNode).prev('.dropdown-header');//closest()?
    console.log($($this[0].parentNode).html());
});
```

but it is saying it cannot find my `dropdown-header` so it is `undefined`. Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:not('dropdown-header')`, `parent()`', and `.prevAll()` to do what you need.

```js
$("li:not('.dropdown-header') a").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().prevAll('li.dropdown-header').data('optgroup'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner">
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="1">
    <a>1</a>Header1</li>
  <li>
    <a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="2">
    <a>4</a>Header2</li>
  <li>
    <a>5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And if they want only the first match, a `.first()` after the `.prevAll()` would do that.

Comment: and if I want the only last match? prevAll is selecting me all matches above, while I need the one that is closest to the clicked `li`

Comment: Clicking 5 or 6 in the example above gives you the optgroup value of two, while clicking 2 or 3 gives you one. What are you expecting?